# nested array does not work

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following problem: I have this multi-level array (nested array) which contains two rows of bitmapData. Row 1:360 rotated bitmapData objects; row 2: 360 rotated and colored bitmapData objects.

I try to access row 2 but that doesn't work. There are some mysterious error messages coming up ("TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@36d7e9e9 to flash.display.BitmapData. at BasicBlitArrayObject/updateFrame()").

Please can someone help me out with this problem? Thank you very much.

this function rotates and colors bitmapData; the rotated bitmapData is thrown into an array and the colored bitmapData is thrown into another array; a third array is used as a level array for nesting the other two arrays inside of it

```
public function     createColoredRotationBlitArrayFromBD(sourceBitmapData:BitmapData, inc:int,     offset:int = 0, color:Number = 1, $alpha:Number = 1):Array
{

tileList = [];
tileListSec = [];
levelArray = [tileList, tileListSec];
var rotation:int = offset; 

while (rotation < (360 + offset))
{
    var angleInRadians:Number = Math.PI * 2 * (rotation / 360);
    var rotationMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

    rotationMatrix.translate(-sourceBitmapData.width * .5, -sourceBitmapData.height * .5);
    rotationMatrix.rotate(angleInRadians);
    rotationMatrix.translate(sourceBitmapData.width * .5, sourceBitmapData.height * .5);


    var matrixImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sourceBitmapData.width, sourceBitmapData.height,
                                true, 0x00000000);

    matrixImage.draw(sourceBitmapData, rotationMatrix);
    tileList.push(matrixImage.clone());


    bitmapData = new BitmapData(matrixImage.width, matrixImage.height, true, 0x00000000);
    bitmapData = matrixImage;


    var colorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter (
                        [color, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, $alpha, 0]);

    matrixImage.applyFilter(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, point0, colorMatrix);


    tileListSec.push(matrixImage.clone());


    rotation += inc;

    matrixImage.dispose();
    matrixImage = null;
    rotationMatrix = null;
    bitmapData.dispose();
    bitmapData = null;
    colorMatrix = null;
    }

return(levelArray);

}
```

creating my rotated and colored bitmapData

```
animationFrames = tempBlitArrayAsset.createRotationBlitArrayFromBD($bitmapData, 1, 270);
```

here I try to access the first row of my level array (that doesn't work; I can't access it)

```
tempEnemy.animationList = animationFrames;
tempEnemy.bitmapData = tempEnemy.animationList[1][tempEnemy.frame];
```

This function is for updating the frames

```
public function updateFrame(inc:int, row:int = 0):void
{
frame += inc;

if (frame > animationList.length - 1){
    frame = 0;
}
bitmapData = animationList[row][frame];                 


}

}
```

this is a line showing how the updateFrame-function is used in my game (trueRotation is 0)

```
tempEnemy.updateFrame(tempEnemy.trueRotation);
```

Comment: It looks like a array is getting pushed in where you expect a bitmapdata to be. Have you tried using strongly typed vectors instead of an array. If you know it's always going to be bitmapdatas in there then it makes sense and it'll throw a runtime exception when you put something in there that doesn't make sense. I'll look at the code in more detail later and see if I can see exactly where it's happening

Comment: no I didn't try a vector yet. Personally I think it's not the problem. Nonetheless I will give this a try later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything wrong with `createColoredRotationBlitArrayFromBD`

```
var $bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(40,40,false, 0x7f7f7f);
var animationFrames:Array = createColoredRotationBlitArrayFromBD($bitmapData, 1, 270);
trace(animationFrames.length);   // 2
trace(animationFrames[0].length);  // 360
trace(animationFrames[1].length);  // 360

var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
this.addChild(bitmap);
bitmap.bitmapData = animationFrames[1][0]; // works..
```

That seems correct. Right? I get a red tinted bitmap.

The only 'bug' I see in the code you listed is in `updateFrame`

```
if (frame > animationList.length - 1){
    frame = 0;
}
```

should probably be:

```
if (frame > animationList[row].length - 1){
    frame = 0;
}
```

because `animationList.length == 2`

But everything else looks okay in the code you've provided, so without more code, i'm not sure there is anything to help.

Comment: Exactly! That was the bug. I discovered the bug 2 days ago and it's working fine now. Thanks for your hint anyway!:)

Comment: Changed this line "if (frame > animationList.length - 1){" to this "if (frame > animationList[row].length - 1){
".